# Will it be possible to develop ubuntu phone apps on ubuntu phones?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, phone

I was hoping that the ubuntu phone would bring true convergence of desktop and mobile operating systems and allow me to ditch all my other devices. I'm a developer and I want to create native applications for the device I'm owning. I dreamed of developing ubuntu phone apps on an ubuntu phone.

I can only find ubuntu SDK downloads for desktop versions of ubuntu.

Am I just missing something? If it's not possible, is this at all intended? Is there any official statement on the matter?

Comment: I'm not aware of any official statement, but I can't imagine wanting to run a compile on the limited resources of a phone. I'd be willing to bet if it was possible that the first try would send me running back to my desktop due to the time involved.

Comment: As Elder Geek said, a phone is *very* limited, and to me it would be *very* unconfortable to develop on a phone, starting with the small screen. In short, I don't think it will be implemented directly, but there will be probably some hack to do so.

Comment: The current phones are probably more powerful than the 8 year old laptop I use. Compiling some source code shouldn't be an insurmountable task.

Answer (score 2):

Full convergence is not yet implemented, and even when it is, many things still will not be entirely feasible on commodity phone hardware, simply due to available resources. When that convergence story is complete, it may be possible to install the SDK directly on the phone, but depending on the hardware you have, it may not actually be feasible to use it; just as it is currently not entirely feasible to use many of the applications on an Ubuntu PC, on extremely low end, or older, hardware.

That said, you can create a *chroot* install of Ubuntu in the home directory of the phone, and install all the console tools needed to develop and build an application. Running graphical tools such as the full SDK may still be problematic though, but may be possible by forwarding a connection to an X display server over ssh.